# How to set onchange based on count using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to set onchange function in  dynamically based on count , for example if 
Count = 2,Need to apply function test() in select

`<select onChange="test()">` Is it possible?

Thanks,
Dinesh Kumar M

Comment: What is count in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If count is the number of options in the select list you can achieve this like so:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var count = $(this).find("option").length;

    switch(count)
    {
        case 1: call1(); break;
        case 2: call2(); break;
        case 3: call3(); break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than encoding it in your select, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(testForChange); // assuming this is the only select on the page
});

function testForChange() {
    // assume count is the value of the selected option
    if($("select option:selected").val() === 2) { 
         test();
    }
}

function test() {
    //...
}
```

With the code written this way you remove the onchange handler from your HTML, a plus for the goal of having unobtrusive Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
   //do something on select change
});
```

[jQuery Ref](http://api.jquery.com/change/)